# Fullscreen a div in HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive, fullscreen

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./lobby_style.css">
    <title>Lobby</title>
</head>

<style>
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide any overflow content */
  background: #EAE8DD;
}
/* Set the .fullscreen div to take up full height */
.fullscreen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.header h1 {
  color: #db5049;
}
.logo {
  width: 150px;
}
.avatar {
  width: 3%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}
.picture-area {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.timer-container {
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.timer-bar {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 1s linear;
}
#guess {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#pixel-image {
  max-height: 800px;
}
.scorelist {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.score-item {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.score-item img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.player-info {
flex: 1;
}
.player-name {
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0;
}
.player-score {
margin: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="fullscreen">
  <div class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="../images/logo.png" alt="Our logo">
    <h1>Lobby ID:</h1>
    <img src="../images/img_avatar.png" alt="Your Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="picture-area">
      <img src="../images/roger.jpeg" id="pixel-image" alt="The pixelated picture">
      <div class="timer-container">
        <div class="timer-bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" name="guess" id="guess" placeholder="Enter your guess">

    <div class="scorelist">
      <div class="score-item">
        <img src="../images/img_avatar.png" alt="profile-picture">
        <div class="player-info">
          <p class="player-name">Kenny</p>
          <p class="player-score">Score: 120</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="score-item">
        <img src="../images/img_avatar.png" alt="profile-picture">
        <div class="player-info">
          <p class="player-name">Cartman</p>
          <p class="player-score">Score: 85</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="score-item">
        <img src="../images/img_avatar.png" alt="profile-picture">
        <div class="player-info">
          <p class="player-name">Stan</p>
          <p class="player-score">Score: 150</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="score-item">
        <img src="../images/img_avatar.png" alt="profile-picture">
        <div class="player-info">
          <p class="player-name">Kyle</p>
          <p class="player-score">Score: 110</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="score-item">
        <img src="../images/img_avatar.png" alt="profile-picture">
        <div class="player-info">
          <p class="player-name">Butters</p>
          <p class="player-score">Score: 75</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="score-item">
        <img src="../images/img_avatar.png" alt="profile-picture">
        <div class="player-info">
          <p class="player-name">Wendy</p>
          <p class="player-score">Score: 200</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add more score items here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically I want the fullscreen div to take up the entire height of any screen. Sometimes (on a laptop for example) I need to scroll out of the site to see everything. This should be fixxed and it should show the entire website without scrolling on any screen. I don't know how to create that...

I tried setting the fullscreen div height to 100vh / 100%, but that doesn't work sadly.

Comment: What means *"without scrolling"*? If there's too much content, and the device is too small or if the screen is resized... that request does not makes too much sense so far... The only odd solution would be to resize the font but that would end up being not readable - is that what you want? Clearly lot since you have the `<!-- Add more score items here -->` therefore something *should indeed* be scrollable. Please [edit] to improve your question and add more clarity.

Comment: You cannot take up the entire screen, you can only take up the entire viewport of the browser.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.